# Object at URL "my website" of type 'website' is invalid because the given value "app id" for property 'fb:app_id' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'

Tags: facebook, app-id

I don't really get why it doesn't work. I also tried fb:admins with my fb id but i get the same error while debugging.

so i tried:
`<meta property="fb:admins" content="{1592996229}"/>`
and
`<meta property="fb:app_id" content="121889277889760" />`
The difference i could make out is that with `fb:admins` gives an error on the website:
`Warning: http://www.cim-gmbh.ch/ is unreachable.`

Answer (score 4):

If 1592996229 is a valid user id, then the code should be:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1592996229"/>
```

not:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="{1592996229}"/>
```

Note the `{}` don't go there...

Answer (score 1):

Check you don't have a redirect or og:url tag pointing to another URL - Facebook will follow that redirect

Also, I can't get any details for that app in the Graph API - did you delete it or restrict it demographically somehow?

Comment: I did infact delete it. I am trying to make my own shoutbox. Despite the problems with it, facebook just isn't fun being so easy to implement. Thanks for the help though.