# Poperty fb:app_id could not be parsed

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-comments

I get this (Object at URL 'http://www.genwnow.com/' of type 'article' is invalid because the given value 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' for property 'fb:app_id' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.) when I try to use this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ on a web page.
The x's represent numbers. I have other fb plugins enabled on the site and when I click see what Facebooks see's on the developer site. I see the fb:app_id in the meta tag. Can I not have FB plug ins installed and use there comments?

Comment: It means the app ID you provided is invalid - check your app ID

Comment: possible duplicate of [Object at URL "my website" of type 'website' is invalid because the given value "app id" for property 'fb:app\_id' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498498/object-at-url-my-website-of-type-website-is-invalid-because-the-given-value)